# Will PCA always fit a model at least as well as NMF?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, non-negative-matrix-factorization

If I perform PCA/NMF on a dataset, and then use the reduced models to reconstruct the original dataset, it seems to me that PCA should typically outperform NMF, simply due to the fact that NMF has the additional restriction of all positive matrix elements. So, are there any guarantees that PCA will outperform (or match) NMF (for the same number of components), perhaps as measured by least-squares or Poisson loss between the original and reconstructed data, or by BIC/AIC?

In Python, an example workflow is:

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF, PCA

X = <some data matrix of shape (n_samples, n_features)>

model_PCA = PCA(n_components=3)
W_PCA = model_PCA.fit_transform(X)
X_recon_PCA = model_PCA.inverse_transform(W_PCA)

model_NMF = NMF(n_components=3)
W_NMF = model_NMF.fit_transform(X)
X_recon_NMF = model_NMF.inverse_transform(W_NMF)
```

What can we say about the "quality" of `X_recon_PCA` vs `X_recon_NMF` compared to the true data matrix `X`?

Comment: Could you clarify by what you mean by "use on"?  Are you including the response variable in the PCA calculation or are you doing PCA on the explanatory variables and then regressing the response against the principal components (a common method of "using" PCA)?

Comment: @whuber I've added some basic python code that hopefully should illustrate, as I'm unfamiliar with the distinction you're making.

Comment: What are you hoping this algorithm will do?  What is the objective or outcome?  If it's only to approximate a dataset, that's purely a means to some other end.  It's hard to see it as a goal in its own right.

Comment: @JaysonVavrek: While not directly related to your question but mostly urged because you mentioned NNMF & Poisson. We might be motivated to use NNMF to capture components among count data cause they are "positive", this might be well-interpretable because it precludes us from having anti-correlated data (e.g. one product sells more at expense of another). Using a generalisation of PCA for Poisson data might be preferable (or simply transforming our data using logs) where we might focus on rates rather than raw counts. I  allude to this at the end of my post.

Comment: @whuber in fact I have two different applications in mind—maybe they line up with your two use cases. 1) The data matrix `X` has many features and I would like a lower-dimension approximation `W` using PCA/NMF. I then want a way to measure how good that approximation is. 2) I have a linear model `y = Xv` and `X` is too large to easily manipulate directly, so I want a lower-dimension approximation `W` via PCA/NMF such that in the approximate linear model, e.g., `y_prime = W v_prime`, `y_prime` is still a close approximation of the original `y`.

Comment: If you perform this analysis on $X$ alone, there's no guarantee either approach will work.  It's possible in either case that the features you retain are orthogonal to $y$ and *all* the useful information is in the features you throw away.  That's why I was interested in how you intend to use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by definition the PCA reconstruction will outperform any other *linear* combination of $k$ components in terms of RSS as it is designed to get the best $k$-rank approximation to the matrix A in terms of least-squares. To quote Pearson's (1901) [On lines and planes of closest fit to systems of points in space](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/147864401094627200): "*the best fitting plane is perpendicular to the greatest axis of the ellipsoid of residuals and the minimum mean square residuals varies inversely as the length of this axis.*" In contrast to that, NNMF components are not constrained to be perpendicular so do not return the optimal reconstruction in terms of RSS.  Please note that they are extensions to a specific member of the exponential family of distributions (e.g.  Bernoulli, Poisson, etc.), Collins et al. (2001) [A Generalization of Principal Components Analysis to the Exponential Family](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2001/hash/f410588e48dc83f2822a880a68f78923-Abstract.html) is an easy to follow and influential reference if you want to read on this further.

Comment: Is Poisson-PCA then similarly guaranteed (by construction) to obtain the best approximation in terms of Poisson loss?

Comment: In effect, yes, as the loss function will depend on which member of the exponential family is used. I would suggest looking at particular implementation for the exact metric used as in quite a few cases, I suspect people might regularise this function too.